# Animations and first load are lags because of css @fontface

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, framer-motion

I have a custom font that I use with @fontface. the font is local. on the first load of the page there's a small lag and every time a new page or a component loads there is the same lag.
if I don't use the custom font there are no lags. Examples below.

this is the css :

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'hebrew';
        src: url(${hebrewFont});
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
    }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:  hebrew;
    font-weight:100;
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
  }
```

this is the lag (You can see it kind of lags/jumps. it looks like it first loads the section with a regular font and then it loads my custom font):

[image]

if I dont use the custom font (it happens with every custom font) there are no lags. see example:

```
  * {
   
    font-family:  Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;
    
  }
```

[image]

thank you for help (: I didn't found this problem at all in the web.

Comment: You can use `font-display: swap;` in your @font-face code in order to display a substitute font until your `custom font` is loaded. Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

Comment: @OzgurSar its not helping the lag. anyway the font is local, its from the project files - so it shouldn't take time to load ? am I wrong?

Comment: Daniel, when you use `swap`, browser renders a standard font until your custom font is loaded. So, for a split second your characters will be displayed in a standard font and as soon as the font is loaded, they will display in your custom font.

Comment: @Daniel have you found a solution to this issue? I've got the same shaky rendering with custom fonts.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 actually not ): , but if your project is not offline just import google font (https://fonts.google.com) . it works for me without lags.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Following [this guide](https://web.dev/codelab-preload-web-fonts/) helped me.

The trick is to preload the fonts in the site's header:

```html
<head>
 <!-- ... -->
 <link rel="preload" href="/assets/Pacifico-Bold.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
</head>
```

This solution eliminated the lag for me, even when using `swap` as suggested in the comments.

Note that it only worked for me when I set `type="font/woff2"` even when my fonts were `.tff`s.